# In Python, how do you annotate a function that accepts a fixed argument as well as any number of other arguments?

Tags: python, function, type-hinting, python-typing, python-3.10

In Python, from my understanding, the ellipsis lets you annotate a function that has any number of arguments ([documentation found here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.Callable)). Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```py
from typing import Callable, Any

def foo(first: str, *rest: Any):
    print(rest)
    return first

def call(f: Callable[[str, ...], str]):
    f("Hello", 1, None, True)

print(call(foo))
```

Python (or, at least, Pylance) doesn't like the ellipsis (`"..." not allowed in this context`): [image: Sceenshot of Pylance hint]

I've tried to use Python 3.10's `ParamSpec`s, but [the documentation on them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) (including [PEP 612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/)) seems to say they're used for other purposes, and I can't tell what those purposes are. Here's what I've tried:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")

def foo(first: str, *rest: Any):
    print(rest)
    return first

def call(f: Callable[Concatenate[str, P], str]):
    f("Hello", 1, None, True)

print(call(foo))
```

Python (or, at least, Pylance) seems to reflect that they aren't meant to be used this way: [image: Screenshot of Pylance hint]

How do I annotate a function like this, that knows the type of one or more of its arguments and accepts any number of other arguments anyway?

Comment: *"There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments; such function types are rarely used as callback types. `Callable[..., ReturnType]` (literal ellipsis) can be used to type hint a callable taking any number of arguments..."* — https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.Callable

Comment: @deceze so are you trying to tell me that there isn't a way to do what i'd like to do?

Comment: *The documentation* is trying to tell you, yes.

Comment: @deceze Apologies, then, I guess I was misreading the documentation. I'm aware of the back end of the snippet you quoted (as I think I made clear in my post), which confused me as to why you were linking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type arbitrary function signatures using `__call__` on a `Protocol`

```
class Foo(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, first: str, *rest: Any) -> str:
        ...

def call(f: Foo):
    f("Hello", 1, None, True)
```